# Comparing two XMLDocument trees with repeating nodes

Tags: java, algorithm, xml-parsing

I am trying to compare two XML files and record all differences. The problem arises, when nodes start to repeat. For two files:

```
<root>
    <a/>
    <a/>
    <b/>
</root>
```

and:

```
<root>
    <a/>
    <b/>
</root>
```

my program currently doesn't record any differences. The (big and ugly) method is as follows:

```
private void searchDocumentTrees (Node nodeA, Node nodeB, ArrayList<String> differences) {
    if (nodeA.hasChildNodes() && !nodeB.hasChildNodes()) {
        // record A deeper at this node
        return;
    }
    else if (!nodeA.hasChildNodes() && nodeB.hasChildNodes()) {
        // record B deeper at this node
        return;
    }

    else if (!nodeA.hasChildNodes() && !nodeB.hasChildNodes()) {
        return;
    }
    NodeList childrenA = nodeA.getChildNodes();
    NodeList childrenB = nodeB.getChildNodes();

    // indexes of nodes present in both lists of children as 
    // NodeList doesn't allow searching by value
    ArrayList<Integer> presentInBothIndexA = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Integer> presentInBothIndexB = new ArrayList<>();

    // check for nodes present in both trees, record those present only in A
    for (int indexA = 0; indexA < childrenA.getLength(); indexA++) {
        boolean isPresentInBoth = false;
        Node currentA = childrenA.item(indexA);
        if (currentA.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

            for (int indexB = 0; indexB < childrenB.getLength(); indexB++) {
                Node currentB = childrenB.item(indexB);
                if (currentB.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                   // if the nodes match, record their indexes and break from inner loop 
                   if (currentA.getNodeName().equals(currentB.getNodeName())) {
                        isPresentInBoth = true;
                        presentInBothIndexA.add(indexA);
                        presentInBothIndexB.add(indexB);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            // if the flag has not been changed currentA is not present in childrenB
            if (!isPresentInBoth) {
                // record as present only in A
            }
        }
    }

    // record nodes present only in B
    for (...){
          /* same nested loop - this time the outer is iterating over B  
          and matching nodes indexes are not recorded - record only B - A */
    }

    for (int indexBoth = 0, len = presentInBothIndexA.size(); indexBoth < len; indexBoth++) {
        Node currentA = childrenA.item(presentInBothIndexA.get(indexBoth));
        Node currentB = childrenB.item(presentInBothIndexB.get(indexBoth));
        searchDocumentTrees(currentA,currentB,differences);
    }



}
```

My first notion was to replace the isPresentInBoth flag for a counter of occurence in both files, but this would probably introduce a third loop thus increasing complexity even more. Do you have a better idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found two solutions:

**SOLUTION 1.**

After trying various (inefficient) approaches e.g. counting occurrences of nodes and storing them in hash tables I realized, that I have structures where I store the indexes of nodes that are identical. This were of course:

`ArrayList<Integer> presentInBothIndexA = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Integer> presentInBothIndexB = new ArrayList<>();`

So instead just letting them hang, I put them to work:

```
// pseudo-code for simplification
for(nodeA in fileA) {
    for(nodeB in fileB) {
         // check all the aforementioned conditions 
         if(presentInBothIndexB.contains(indexB))
             continue; // skip if it was already recorded
         // else, do all the other stuff - isPresentInBoth = true, and so on
```

Now the second loop does not need an inner loop:

```
for (nodeB in B) {
    if (!presentInBothIndexB.contains(indexB))
         //record difference - we only need to look for the nodes, that were skipped
         //by the first loop, i.e. not present in file A
```

This approach has its disadvantages, as it compares the nodes in the order they were put in the files so in the case:

```
<r>
  <a/>
  <a/>
  <a><b/></a>
</r>
```

and:

```
<r>
  <a/>
  <a/>
</r>
```

it would record that there is a different number of nodes  but would not search deeper in the first file. This is due to the fact, that after recording the two nodes as identical it simply does not look further. That is a nuisance, but I guess we could make that assumption. But then, there are also attributes and values to compare and the whole thing gets messier and messier, which brings mi to:

**SOLUTION 2.** 
Just use [XMLUnit](http://www.xmlunit.org/). Seriously.